# Cross Origin Request errors for my own JS file but not for external libraries. why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm following this example to try to get React working on my computer.

https://gist.github.com/danawoodman/9cfddb1a0c934a35f31a

I note that I don't have access to a server and I can't install anything on this computer so I'm trying to get a site displaying just using the c: or file:// path.

This is my index.html code. Note I have saved the react, react-dom and browser scripts locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='root'></div>
    <script src="extfiles/react.js"></script>
    <script src="extfiles/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="extfiles/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="extfiles/scripts.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My scripts.js file is simply

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm getting this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///<path>/extfiles/scripts.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.transform.load @ browser.min.js:4
```

I understand why I'm getting this error from posts such as ["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/38320697#38320697).

What I don't understand is why I don't get this error loading up the react library but only when I load up my own files. Because if I change

```
<script src="extfiles/scripts.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

to

```
    <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Then that works indicating to me that ReactDOM has been loaded.

Comment: `...so I'm trying to get a site displaying just using the c: or file:// path.`  This is your problem. The content must be served via http/https

Comment: You can start a web server simply by `python -mSimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: loading a script using script tag has no "cross origin" limitations

Comment: @AnthonyKong : yeah i know - but what I'm trying to understand is why i can load the react library but not my own files.

Comment: "extfiles/scripts.js" is a relative path or the URL. probably being translated to something like http://localhost:8080/extfiles/scripts.js. While "file:///<path>/extfiles/scripts.js", this is reading a file from disk directly, not from server, that's why it's complaining about XSS.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answers given in the comments since this seems to be a common problem for new React developers.

The cross-origin request error the browser generates when you try to load a local file exists to prevent [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) which involves injecting local scripts into a webpage and the server trusting those scripts.

Because of this, you can't load local scripts; you need to serve them over HTTP or HTTPS instead. A simple way to do this is to use a local web server such as [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info) or, as @AnthonyKong said in a comment, Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver) feature.

Additionally, React has a developer tools plugin for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/react-devtools) that gives you the option to allow local scripts for development.